# So’ton abbreviation

Tags: football, trivia

[image]Why do some sports media and broadcasters (eg Sky Sports) routinely abbreviate Southampton FC to So’ton when they don’t abbreviate other, longer club names? For example, take the PL fixtures from this weekend: So’ton v Tottenham on the one hand but Norwich City v Crystal Palace on the other.

Comment: Do you have any images demonstrating this? I'd be surprised if they abbreviated "Southampton" to "So'ton" but not "Norwich City" to e.g. "Norwich".

Comment: Now added as requested

Answer (score 1):

If this were something that happened consistently on all platform, it would be safe to assume that it is an official abbreviation that the team prefers to use. However, in the given case, and judging from the way you have framed the question, this is not something that happens consistently, instead differs from platform to platform. Therefore, it is safe to assume that is is a "design decision" by the people who are running the platform under consideration.